# How do i delete everything after the last occurance of # in a name?

Tags: notepad++, hashing

I've got many files, all start with the date in the year-month-day format, then the name, and then a #with a string of numbers after it. Examples -

```
2018-03-24 - file name one #458934
```

Now, I've figured out how to just remove everything after #, however some files have names like:

```
2019-03-16 - #one file #two the rest of the name #435943
2020-06-21 - part of the name #another part of the name #458929
```

I want to remove everything after the last occurrence of `#` for each file, so on some files that will be everything after the only occurrence of # but on other files it could be the second or third # that I'd want to remove everything after.

With the above examples, I'd want them to end up as:

```
2018-03-24 - file name one
2019-03-16 - #one file #two the rest of the file name
2020-06-21 - part of the name #another part of the name
```

I've tried searching but the results I found were for deleting everything after different characters than # or after a specific number of occurrences of the character, and I've not been able to figure out how to adjust those answers in order to make them work for me.

Comment: Are you using notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using Notepad++, do the following:

- Find what: `^(.+)#.+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`

You can use the same regular expression with PowerRename or Powershell.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @MarkC If your question has been successfully anwered, please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).